# N-dimensional arrays in R with numpy-like broadcasting?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I am using the Gauss-Laguerre quadrature to approximate an integrate for every point in a large matrix. Currently I to evaluate the the function over the entire matrix at each node and sum the matrices in a `for` loop. While not terribly slow, the function takes ~ 1 sec with ~ 2e6 points and ~ 30 nodes, and I want to use the function in an expectation-maximization routine.  Calculating the `weights[i]*func(nodes[i], x, mu)` (x is matrix of points and mu is row-specific local mean), is fast with R's built in vectorization, so I think the slowdown is (unsurprisingly) the loop over the matrices. With ndarrays in numpy, I would just reshape each array such that the result would be broadcast to a n by m by p array, with n,m as the dimensions of x, and p as the number of nodes, and sum along the last dimension. The multi-way arrays in R don't seem to have such functionality; operations seem to only work on arrays of the same shape. Though it would be trivial to copy the data into the same shape, 4 arrays with ~ 2e6 elements seems like a waste. Is there another package/structure for multi-dimensional arrays in R with broadcasting rules similar to numpys? Code below. Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023845/canonical-form-for-marginal-liklihood-integral-random-variable-from-exponential/2027465#2027465) for context.

```
integral.local <- function(x, mu, func, params) {
  # func must be vectorized for x and mu
  integral.sums <- matrix(0,nrow = nrow(x), ncol= ncol(x))
  for (i in 1:length(nodes)){
    integral.sums <- integral.sums + weights[i]*func(nodes[i], x, mu, params)
  }
  integral.sums
}

pow.const.func <- function (theta, x, mu, params) {
  # for use in Gauss-Laguerre quadrature
  # implicitly assumes phi > 0
  # vectorized for x and mu
  s <- exp(1/2*params['beta0'])*(params['phi']*theta + mu)^
    (1/2*params['beta1'])
  tmp <- x-(params['phi']*theta + mu)
  1/(sqrt(2*pi)*s)*exp(-tmp*tmp/(2*s*s))
}
```

EDIT: My benchmark was off. That was based on `system.time` when I used `repmat` to copy `mu` into the shape of `x` before looping. Below is `microbenchmark` for the function as above for 39 nodes. Not nearly as bad a ~ 1 sec, but I still wouldn't mind an order of magnitude speed up.

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
integral.local  216.8249 219.7517 233.6998 220.9933 225.3213 1044.216   100
```

Comment: Maybe `sweep` would be useful here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Imo Could you elaborate? My first implementation used `mapply` and `sweep` to perform the summation over each cell individually, which was slower than the current `for` loop. But perhaps if I change `func` to sum over all theta for a given x and mu?

Comment: @ Imo I wasn't able to make a working function with `sweep` without using `mapply`. As I just remembered, `sweep` requires a function vectorized for `x` and `mu` since that function is only excuted once on `x` and a matrix of equal size made from `mu`. In native R, it seems I can only vectorize for theta by either a (very slow) nested for loop or (still slow) `apply`-type method. I suspect that the vectorized functions are done in C while `mapply` executes a loop in R, and so my second implementation is faster than the first.

Comment: could you do this with appropriate use of `aperm()`?